# Relative import not working when importing module from within the same package

Tags: python-3.x, python-import

I have the following structure:

```
ds/
    BST.py
    BSTNode.py
```

When I do

```
from .BSTNode import BSTNode
```

inside `BST.py`, and I run from the **IDLE** `BST.py` from within `ds` I receive the following error:

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Why am I receiving it? Note that I am not asking how to fix the problem, because it would work if I simply do

```
from BSTNode import BSTNode
```

i.e. without the leading `.`. I just want to understand better how the Python's import system works.

Note that theoretically I should not need any `__init__.py` within `ds` because I am using Python 3.5. If I am not clear enough, just ask!

Thank you!!!!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72852/how-to-do-relative-imports-in-python

Comment: @Apero It doesn't help. The first answer says that the problem is that by running a module I am running it as "main", and therefore there's no package information. How do I add package information to my module? I am not running the module from the terminal but from the IDLE. And I would like that it works in both situations.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11536764/attempted-relative-import-in-non-package-even-with-init-py

Comment: @Apero I still was not able to solve my problem. I set the `__package__` attribute manually to `ds` after checking that `.../ds` in on the path, but I still have the following error: `SystemError: Parent module 'ds' not loaded, cannot perform relative import` when importing like `from .BSTNode import BSTNode`.

Comment: Does adding a blank `__init__.py` help?  I have never tried relative imports because too many people have problems trying to use them.

Comment: @TerryJanReedy I have already it. It's incredible how something such important doesn't work decently. I am so frustrated.

Comment: me to, seems like one of the ugliest faces of python ....